# EF7 Implement TPH + M2M

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there a better way to accomplish this end-goal of having easily-queryable (and Include-able) cross-sections of a related many-to-many entity stored in the same table?

I started off without implementing TPH in the join table, but that makes consuming one type or another in queries more involved, afaict.

```
// table Related: [Id]
public class Related
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedOther> RelatedOthers { get; set; } = new List<RelatedOther>();
    public List<RelatedOtherOne> RelatedOtherOnes { get; set; } = new List<RelatedOtherOne>();
    public List<RelatedOtherTwo> RelatedOtherTwos { get; set; } = new List<RelatedOtherTwo>();
}

// table RelatedOther: [RelatedId, OtherId, Type]
public abstract class RelatedOther
{
    public Guid RelatedId { get; set; }
    public Guid OtherId { get; set; }

    public Related Related { get; set; }
    public Other Other { get; set; }
    public abstract RelatedOtherType Type { get; }
}
public class RelatedOtherOne : RelatedOther
{
    public override RelatedOtherType Type => RelatedOtherType.One;
    // should be unnecessary, 'Other' should be correct type
    public OtherOne OtherOne { get; set; }
}
public class RelatedOtherTwo : RelatedOther
{
    public override RelatedOtherType Type => RelatedOtherType.Two;
    // should be unnecessary, 'Other' should be correct type
    public OtherTwo OtherTwo { get; set; }
}
public enum  RelatedOtherType : int
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}

// table Other: [Id, OneProp, TwoProp]
public abstract class Other
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedOther> RelatedOthers { get; set; } = new List<RelatedOther>();
}
public class OtherOne : Other
{
    public string OneProp { get; set; }
}
public class OtherTwo : Other
{
    public string TwoProp { get; set; }
}
```

TPH is mapped [like this](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relational/inheritance.html#id4)
M2M is mapped [like this](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#id21) + discriminator in HasKey()

This gets even more complicated (if not impossible?) when the 'Related' entity evolves into a TPH strategy like the 'Other'.

Answer (score 0):

I have no easy solution but as I stumbled across the same problem I thought I'll share what I have so far.

I found out that I usually need to load all or many types of the relations to the classes of a TPH structure.

So I use the base many-to-many class to load the related objects. Thus this class cannot be abstract:

```
public class Event2Location
{
    [Required]
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public byte EntityType { get; set; }
}
```

The derived class only adds some properties for easier access:

```
public class Event2Country : Event2Location
{
    [NotMapped]
    public Country Country
    {
        get { return base.Location as Country; }
        set { base.Location = value; }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public int CountryId
    {
        get { return base.LocationId; }
        set { base.LocationId = value; }
    }
}
```

In the `Event` class I have:

```
public virtual ICollection<Event2Location> Event2Locations { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public virtual ICollection<Event2Country> Event2Countries => Event2Locations?.OfType<Event2Country>().ToList();
// I should probably add some caching here if accessed more often

[NotMapped]
public virtual ICollection<Event2City> Event2Cities => Event2Locations?.OfType<Event2City>().ToList();
```

So when I load the joined tables I can use

```
.Include(e => e.Event2Locations).ThenInclude(j => j.Location)
```

And I can access the relations of a specific type as needed with the NotMapped Collections.

I still use the derived Event2... classes to add a new relationship.

As you see I have added a column `EntityType` to the many-to-many class which I use as TPH discriminator. With this column I can also declare which types of Relations/entities I want to load if I do not want to load all.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event2Location>()
    .HasDiscriminator<byte>("EntityType")
    .HasValue<Event2Location>(0)
    .HasValue<Event2Country>(1)
```

This is surely far from perfect but I finally gave up on optimizing that. First EFCore has to become more mature. Second I want to see how I actually use these structures.

PS: Actually my Location TPH structure has parent-child-relationships within it. Here I did not create a TPH structure for the relation class (as you said - not possible or at least not reasonable). I added ParentType and ChildType. Thus I can determine which relations I actually want to load. Then I fetch the related Locations of the types I need manually on the client side from the result.

Comment: I decided that if the ends of the m2m association are TPH, then the join table itself should also reflect that TPH, regardless of whether or not I expose Navigation properties on either end for all of those TPH types. It's just a cleaner design imo. This will then allow the framework to handle the Navigation property translation that you have as `[NotMapped]` using the cast.

Comment: And when I use `abstract` on my base class it doesn't prevent me from querying just on that base type - if the query results in more than one derived type as a result set, EF will instantiate the correct derived type and the instance in the corresponding derived type will automatically be populated with that instance. If your model has 2 (and only 2) derived types, then the base class should be abstract. An instance of Event2Location without an EventType discriminator value doesn't really make sense, right? So you should never be able to create a vanilla instance of Event2Location.